# Populate dropdowns with one useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this useEffect which is used to load content for dropdowns displayed into 2 components:

App.js

```
useEffect(() => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            credentials: 'include',
        };

        fetch('/portfolios', requestOptions)
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status !== 200) {
                    throw new Error(response.status);
                } else {
                    return response.json();
                }
            })
            .then(
                (portfolios) => {
                    props.onSetPortfolios(portfolios);
                    props.onSetFuturesPortfolios(portfolios);
                },
                (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            );
    }, []);


export const SET_PORTFOLIOS = 'portfolios:addPortfolios';

export function setPortfolios(portfolios) {
    return {
        type: SET_PORTFOLIOS,
        payload: portfolios
    }
}
```

...

```
<FormControl variant="outlined">
                <Autocomplete
                    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                        props.onUpdatePortfolio(newInputValue);
                    }}
                    id="futures-portfolio-select"
                    options={props.portfolios}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.portfolio_label}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Portfolio" variant="outlined" />}
                    />
            </FormControl>
```

.....

Second similar dropdown located into another page

```
<FormControl variant="outlined">
                    <Autocomplete
                        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
                            props.onUpdatePortfolio(newInputValue);
                        }}
                        id="futures-portfolio-select"
                        options={props.portfolios}
                        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.portfolio_label}
                        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Portfolio" variant="outlined" />}
                        />
                </FormControl>
```

......

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    portfolios: state.portfolios
});
```

I noticed that when I open the SPA app holding the second dropdown the first time it's empty. Into the second page I have to refresh the page when I load it for the first time. Is there some way to reuse the data from this useEffect or implement some kind of waiting action without the need of page refresh?

How I can reuse the data into different components using the same data from useEffect?

Comment: This appears to be nearly identical to the question you posted 5 hours ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70085594/reuse-useeffect-into-several-places

Comment: Yes, I made a cleanup